# Как передать значения двумерного массива из теста (Junit) в тестируемый метод

Tags: java

Есть метод, который переворачивает массив на 90 градусов.

```
public int[][] rotate(int[][] array) {
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length / 2; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < array.length - 1; j++) {
            int tmp = array[i][j];
            array[i][j] = array[j][array.length - 1 - i];
            array[j][array.length - 1 - i] = array[array.length - 1 - i][array.length - 1 - j];
            array[array.length - 1 - i][array.length - 1 - j] = array[array.length - 1 - j][i];
            array[array.length - 1 - j][i] = tmp;
        }
    }
    return array;
```

При написании теста ругается на синтаксис

```
public class RotateArrayTest {
@Test
public void whenRotateTwoRowTwoColArrayThenRotatedArray() {
    RotateArray rotateArray = new RotateArray();
    int[][] resultArray = rotateArray.rotate(new int[][] {1, 2}{3, 4});
    int[][] expectArray = new int[][] {3, 1}{4, 2};
    assertThat(resultArray, is(expectArray));
}
```

конкретно на строчки

```
int[][] resultArray = rotateArray.rotate(new int[][] {1, 2}{3, 4});
int[][] expectArray = new int[][] {3, 1}{4, 2};
```

Хотя, для одномерного массива запись

```
int[] resultArray = turn.back(new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5});
```

вполне допустима и правильна.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Объявление нужно еще в одни скобки обернуть и запятую между вложенными массивами не забыть:

```
int[][] resultArray = rotateArray.rotate(new int[][] { {1, 2}, {3, 4} });
int[][] expectArray = new int[][] { {3, 1}, {4, 2} };
```